# Terraform - Launch in specific availability zones in any region

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, mapping, terraform, subnet

I am looking to launch a subnet in the 'a' or 'b' availability zone of any region I specify - is there a way I can allow terraform to do this?

Something along the lines of this:

```
variable "az" {
  default = {
    a = 1
    b = 2
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  availability_zone = var.az.(places subnets in either of the specified AZs)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply take the current region name, and append the `a` or `b` characters to it, like so:

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}

locals {
 az1 = "${data.aws_region.current.name}a"
 az2 = "${data.aws_region.current.name}b"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is a fine answer for the question as posed. I'm writing this answer to show an alternative that doesn't directly solve the problem as posed but would achieve an equivalent result in any region where you have access to both the `a` and `b` AZs:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "all" {
}

locals {
  sorted_availability_zones   = sort(data.aws_availability_zones.all.names)
  selected_availability_zones = toset([
    local.sorted_availability_zones[0],
    local.sorted_availability_zones[1],
  ])
}

resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = local.selected_availability_zones

  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  availability_zone = each.value
}
```

The above uses [the `aws_availability_zones` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/availability_zones) to find all of the zones your account has access to in the current region, then sorts them lexically so that they will be in a predictable order, and finally takes the first two items from that sorted list. Assuming you have access to the `a` and `b` zones this will always pick those two, because (per the current AZ naming scheme) they will always sort first in the list.